# How do I export a JIRA report to PDF?

Tags: pdf, jira, jira-plugin

I would like to export JIRA reports (e.g. Burndown Chart) in PDF format. I assumed this would be relatively low level functionality, but I cannot see a way to do this. I have searched for plugins and while some export issues or other things to PDF, I cannot find plugins for JIRA Cloud that export reports to PDF.

Is there a way to do this? If so, how? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it looks like this is not possible with JIRA currently and there is even an open issue for implementing something that would be close to what you are looking for : https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/JSW-6135

Comment: Thank you for this response. It is unfortunate. I hope they get to this soon. I frankly would gladly pay someone to build this functionality (and release it for free).

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it works but,

Right click on the report page, and then print. During print you will see option save or print.

Try to save it as pdf.

Comment: This technically gets it into PDF, but it's not exported in a way that is visually pleasing or easy to navigate.